# fade-out and fade-in to another image at the same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have written a code that making fade-in and fade-out the images using this js function:

```
 function fade(){
 $('#image').fadeOut(500);
  setTimeout(function () { showNew(img); }, 500);
  $('#image').fadeIn(500);
}   
 <img src="#" id="image" height="500" width="auto">
```

But it's fade-out to white background then the next image fade-in from the white background also.
i need a function which make the image fade-out to another image not to the background

Comment: You might want to include the code for showNew() you could also create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed a non-jQuery javascript to build changing images into my wife's site. (self promotion)[beatricehamblett.com](http://beatricehamblett.com)(/self promotion)

The script is as follows:

```
    // You need to style the css for the image as follows: 
#image1{visibility:hidden};
    //-->


function fadeIn(objId,opacity) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        obj = document.getElementById(objId);
        if (opacity <= 100) {
            setOpacity(obj, opacity);
            opacity += 2;
            window.setTimeout("fadeIn('"+objId+"',"+opacity+")", 100);
        }
    }
}

function initImage() {
    imageId = 'image1';
    image = document.getElementById(imageId);
    setOpacity(image, 0);
    image.style.visibility = "visible";
    fadeIn(imageId,0);
}

function setOpacity(obj, opacity) {
    opacity = (opacity == 100)?99.999:opacity;
    // IE/Win
    obj.style.filter = "alpha(opacity:"+opacity+")";
    // Safari<1.2, Konqueror
    obj.style.KHTMLOpacity = opacity/100;
    // Older Mozilla and Firefox
    obj.style.MozOpacity = opacity/100;
    // Safari 1.2, newer Firefox and Mozilla, CSS3
    obj.style.opacity = opacity/100;
}


window.onload = function() {
initImage();
};
```

It can be used as many times as needed, to serve multiple images

Answer (score 0):

There is no jQuery function for that.

What I usually do is putting the images behind each other with CSS and leave the background color transparent. Then when you fade out the image on the front it looks like it fades into the other image with z-index and position absolute:

```
.image-front {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   z-index:2;
}

.image-back {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   z-index:1;
}
```

Here's a trivial example: http://jsfiddle.net/bullfrogg/Wc6Yu/1/
For your case: just set the background to transparent and put images in the divs.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you need is cross fade between images. To achieve this, you can use `z-index` property and stack two images on top of each other. Then you can simply fadeOut the upper one.

Here is an example that will help you http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/simple-jquery-image-crossfade/

Comment: thanks for your help, but i can't apply this to my code because the images exists in folder, and i display them by getting their paths to an array ... so i need a several function to do what i want

Comment: Please create a fiddle, that will help understand your problem better.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7NArn/
there is all my code
but it will not work because it need to folder of images